# why is the child function not getting called while inheriting a singleton in c++

Tags: c++

I have the following test code. Here, the output is "from parent", how can I call the child function? Why is the child function not getting called? is is recommended to inherit from a singleton?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Singleton
{
    public:
    static Singleton& getInstance()
    {
        static Singleton s;
        return s; 
    }
    virtual void func()
    {
        cout << "from parent" << endl;
    }
};

class Child : public Singleton
{
    public:
    void func() override
    {
        cout << "from child" << endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    Singleton& s = Child::getInstance();
    s.func();
}
```

Comment: To call `Child::func()` you need an object of type `Child` (or possibly a type derived from that). Which line in your code constructs an object of type `Child`?

Comment: `getInstance` returns a reference to a `Singleton` object, not a `Child` object.

Comment: I suppose if you wanted to have a singleton with child classes without wanting to rewrite `getInstance` for each one you could use the CRTP but it's not clear why you would want to. What are you trying to do with this pattern?

Comment: Hi @NathanPierson The parent class is used for actual implementation, and the child class will have some specific dummy implementations to bypass some operations. The child will be used for testing certain sections of the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, `Singleton::getInstance` always returns a `Singleton`. `Child` doesn't have its own version of `getInstance`, so `Child::getInstance()` resolves to a call to `Singleton::getInstance()` which returns a `Singleton`, not a `Child`. If we use the CRTP, we can make it so `Singleton::getInstance` actually knows the derived type we're trying to get an instance of:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <class Derived>
class Singleton
{
public:
    static Derived& getInstance()
    {
        // Assert that the template arg really is derived from the appropriate instantiation of the base class template
        static_assert(std::is_base_of<Singleton<Derived>, Derived>::value);
        static Derived s;
        return s;
    }
    virtual void func()
    {
        std::cout << "from parent" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Child : public Singleton<Child>
{
public:
    void func() override
    {
        std::cout << "from child" << std::endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    auto& s = Child::getInstance(); // s is a Child here
    s.func(); // Outputs "from child" as expected
}
```